# I have the problem with PyVirtualDisplay==0.2.5 package for running tests with usage of virtual displays (headless mode)

Tags: python, macos, selenium, headless, pyvirtualdisplay

My tests are working and running as expected with `PyVirtualDisplay==0.2.1`, but I have a problem with the latest version of this package (for example, `PyVirtualDisplay==0.2.5`).

My code snippet:

```
...
    def _set_up(self):

        # Creation of instance of the browser.
        self.display = Display(visible=0, size=(config.WIDTH, config.HEIGHT))
        self.display.start()
        desired = self.get_desired_capabilities(config.BROWSER)
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=config.ACTIVE_NODE,
                                       desired_capabilities=desired)
        # Maximize window size.
        self.driver.set_window_size(config.WIDTH, config.HEIGHT)
...
```

Error message:

> Error Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/case.py",
>   line 59, in testPartExecutor
>       yield   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/case.py",
>   line 624, in run
>       self.setUp()   File "/Users/ratmirasanov/Documents/testing/welcome_widget/test_welcome_widget.py",
>   line 24, in setUp
>       self._set_up()   File "/Users/ratmirasanov/Documents/testing/utilities.py", line 41, in
>   _set_up
>       self.display.start()   File "/Users/ratmirasanov/Documents/testing/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/abstractdisplay.py",
>   line 171, in start
>       raise XStartTimeoutError(msg % d) pyvirtualdisplay.abstractdisplay.XStartTimeoutError: Failed to start X
>   on display ":1001" (xdpyinfo check failed).

I did not find any working solution to fix this problem. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

UPD: The `PyVirtualDisplay==0.2.5` package is working as expected on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

Where is located the `xdpyindo` program: `/usr/bin/xdpyinfo`.

The problem is on my Mac (macOS Catalina 10.15.2) with XQuartz (https://www.xquartz.org/index.html) installed (`xdpyindo` program is located in `/opt/X11/bin/xdpyinfo` folder).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a workaround 'xdpyinfo' program can be removed on Mac.

Here is a discussion inside the created issue on the project's repository on GitHub: https://github.com/ponty/PyVirtualDisplay/issues/42

UPD: Actually, it was a permission problem. It can be fixed after doing the following actions (without removing 'xdpyinfo' program):

```
mkdir /tmp/.X11-unix 
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp/.X11-unix 
sudo chown root /tmp/.X11-unix/
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me on this issue as well.

Comment: @EzraGoss, nice!

Answer (score 0):

> My tests are working and running as expected with PyVirtualDisplay==0.2.1

Your display is taking longer than 10 secs to start.  This constraint didn't exist in old versions of PyVirtualDisplay.

Explanation:

Starting with version `0.2.2`, PyVirtualDisplay relies on the `xdpyinfo` program to determine if an X server is running with a given timeout.  It only tries to start the display for 10 seconds and then raises a `XStartTimeoutError`.

https://github.com/ponty/PyVirtualDisplay/commit/3b11cf1e1381921c047ba18f4c5d929847f23b84