# Importing Selenium and xdpyinfo

Tags: selenium, pythonanywhere

**after importing:**
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

**I get this message:** 
xdpyinfo was not found, X start can not be checked! Please install xdpyinfo!

Comment: Maybe it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59530551/i-have-the-problem-with-pyvirtualdisplay-0-2-5-package-for-running-tests-with-u

Comment: I believe that's just a warning message; your Selenium code will still work.